# WinUI 3 rounded main window

Tags: c#, desktop-application, winui-3

How to make main window with rounded corners?
I had a look on many videos and steps are quite simple.

- check SDK installed
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFrSs.png)
- create project c# Windows WinUI
- run app - after that a MainWindow appears with rounded corners.

But when project created by me the Mainwindow without rounded corners.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnZiy.png)

Maybe I have to update windows up to 11?

Comment: Windows 10 does not support rounded corners, so your Winui3 window won't have them too. But when you update to windows 11 you will get them.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I have to update windows up to 11?

Yes, correct.

Only on **Windows 11**, the system automatically rounds top-level window corners for most apps as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

The APIs that apply rounded corners are not present in Windows 10 and earlier versions.